# If a server has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, how does the DNS determine which to return? See the following example

Tags: ip, ipv4, ipv6, dns

These Pings were done at different times of the same day:

C:\Users\LPress>ping www.ucla.edu
Pinging gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu [164.67.228.152] with 32 bytes of data:

C:\Users\LPress>ping www.ucla.edu
Pinging gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu [2607:f010:2e8:228:0:ff:fe00:152] with 32 bytes of data:

Comment: It depends on the OS, which is off topic here but normally IPv6 is preferred over IPv4, when both are available.

Comment: DNS returns whatever is asked for. "any" (which is rarely supported these days) will return all records for the requested name, "A" IPv4, and "AAAA" IPv6. How you ask (v4/v6) doesn't matter. What the application or OS chooses to asked is app/OS specific -- and doubly off-topic.